# Any stellar entity named A1?

Tags: naming, stellar-classification

Is there a spatial entity (moon, planet, star, system, galaxy, cluster,..) that is identified with "A1" (or A{first_term})?

Comment: Not really… can you provide some context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Lowell observatory gives temporary designations in the form "A-number" to objects that it studies. A1 would be a temporary designation that the Lowell observatory could give an object.  For example

> NGC 3603-A1 is likely the most massive binary star ever “weighed” through its orbital mass. [...]  We have also produced a light curve for **A1** using HST photometry, which provides a more accurate measurement of the systems inclination. Ultimately we hope to refine the masses of **A1** with new observations. [Source](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2021AAS...23713305B/abstract)

There is an object (1)  it is (1) Ceres, the dwarf planet. And 1P is Halley's comet.

Comment: thx, know a resource to the naming conventions for celestial bodies?

Comment: The minor planet centre for official names.  Wikipeida has a list of the temporary codes that various observatories conventionally give objects of study. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provisional_designation_in_astronomy  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_naming_conventions

Comment: Using MPC, I found two other entries which have "A1" in their name: C/2021 A1 (Leonard), A/2020 A1 (A/NEOWISE) [cc @user406126]

Answer (score 2):

A quick check with the [Simbad database](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-fid) shows nothing with the identifier "A1".

A search on the [NASA Extragalactic Database](http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/byname) turns up the galaxy cluster Abell 1 (or "Abell 0001", as NED puts it), which *might* qualify, in that people will sometimes refer to Abell clusters using just "A" + the number (e.g., "Abell 496" gets a short name of "A496"). But that's an informal practice, so I'd conclude there aren't any celestal objects with a permanent/formal name of "A1".